# Tinymce | Link plugin | How to disable URL menu?

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-4

Currently when I use TinyMce4.5.1 with Link plugin. I cannot find a way to hide default URL options(#top, #bottom) even I set property link_list to false. Is there a proper way for me to do this besides hacking the original source code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just figured out.

```
'anchor_bottom': false,
'anchor_top': false
```